# Пустой кусок страницы

Tags: html, css

Создал текст. Текст отображается "Новосибирская.Обл" Но при этом создаётся пустой кусок страницы. Как его убрать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}

.UpShapka {
  width: 100%;
  height: 121px;
  background-color: #383333;
}

.DownShapka {
  top: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 274px;
  background-color: #3e3b3b;
}

.header {
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 121px;
  background-color: #373535;
}

.header2 {
  top: 120px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 274px;
  background-color: #3d3939;
}

.p2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 1200px;
  top: -290px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NameSite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="UpShapka">
    <div class="header">
      <p><img src="logo.png" style="width:250px;height:95px;color:background-color:white; margin-left: 30px;margin-top:15px;"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="DownShapka" <header2>
    <p><img src="Prius.png" style="width:566px;height:383px; margin-top:-50px;margin-left: 550px;"></p>
    <p class="p2">Новосибирская обл</p>
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style=" position:relative; left:1150px;top:-320px; font-size:40px;color:white;"></i>
    </header2>
  </div>
  <span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а position:relative;  left :1200px это что такое ?

Comment: Свободное перемещение(position:relative)

Comment: какое же оно свободное ? оно создаёт сбоку пространство - очевидно о этом вы говорите

Comment: Тогда какой position использовать? Тогда как перемещать?

Comment: а какая задача ?

Comment: Перемещение текста , чтобы при отображение появлялся сам текст. Я так понимаю можно сделать с помощью margin-left? margin-top?

Comment: margin любой также отобразит полосу прокрутки - можно сделать некий блок  с overflow:hidden и спрятать текст за его пределами ... и при событие hover показать его ...применять лучше в этом случае transform:translateY() а в скобках указать либо минусовое значение либо положительное ...

Comment: <header2> новый тег?